# Jailed user has no access to network

Tags: networking, debian

I have a Debian 10 server running ISPConfig. As of today, jailed users can't access any network (other than 127.0.0.1/localhost). Ping doesn't work at all.

On Friday afternoon, I ran `git push` with no problems. This morning, I tried to push another commit and got:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user/repo/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

Output of a few commands which might be helpful:

```bsh
$ ping google.com
ping: socket: Operation not permitted

$ wget google.com
--2020-03-01 14:28:13--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'google.com'

$ wget 8.8.8.8
--2020-03-01 14:29:27--  http://8.8.8.8/
Connecting to 8.8.8.8:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

(It tried a few more times, but the output was exactly the same.)

I've been Googling for around the past three hours, but there doesn't seem to be much documentation for jailkit online.

Thank you!

(There isn't even a tag for jailkit on Superuser! If they were available, I would have added tags `jailkit` and `ispconfig`.)

Comment: This link may help, but I don't know if it is what you are looking for https://askubuntu.com/questions/93411/simple-easy-way-to-jail-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be pretty simple, and very specific to me. I recently changed my router. The new router had a gateway IP 192.168.1.1, however the old one had been 192.168.1.254. It turns out that the jails `/etc/resolv.conf` hadn't been updated, so it was still trying to use the old gateway. After updating that, everything worked.